# Changing the Scale of an object in one direction only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cylinder that moves with Translate, I need the platform to always be near the center of the cylinder. As in the photo below.

[image].

To do this, I wrote a script that calculates how far the cylinder has moved, and adds this number to the platform scale and adds this number divided by two to the platform Z position.

```cs
if (transform.position.z > spawnedBlocks[spawnedBlocks.Count - 1].transform.position.z)
{
  zDistance = transform.position.z - spawnedBlocks[spawnedBlocks.Count - 1].transform.position.z;
  spawnedBlocks[spawnedBlocks.Count - 1].transform.position = new Vector3(spawnedBlocks[spawnedBlocks.Count - 1].transform.position.x, spawnedBlocks[spawnedBlocks.Count - 1].transform.position.y, spawnedBlocks[spawnedBlocks.Count - 1].transform.position.z + (zDistance / 2));
  spawnedBlocks[spawnedBlocks.Count - 1].transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0.1f, spawnedBlocks[spawnedBlocks.Count - 1].transform.localScale.z + zDistance);
}
```

This code is in my Fixed Update and it turns out that the platform moves much faster and goes forward.

Comment: It happens with spaghetti code ;)

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake you make is in the positioning.

Cleaned up a bit your code looks somewhat like this:

```
var myPos = transform.position;
var block = spawnedBlocks[spawnedBlocks.Count - 1].transform;
var blockPos = block.position;

if (myPos.z > blockPos.z)
{
    zDistance = myPos.z - blockPos.z;

    block.position += Vector3.forward * zDistance / 2f;

    block.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0.1f, block.z + zDistance);
}
```

But now have a careful look what you are doing here:

- if the `myPos.z` is bigger than `blockPos.z` you will move it forward

Now wait a minute! Shouldn't it rather stay at the **center** between its original spot and the `myPos`?

Example:

1. Let's say both objects start at `z=0`.
2. Now the `myPos` moves to `z=2` (just example numbers)

   - `zDistance = 2`
   - you move the block to current position + half of distance so `0 + 1`
3. This frame you don't move at all (easier to explain this way)

- `myPos.z` (2) is **still bigger** than `blockPos.z` (1)
- so distance is now `1`
- you move the block to current position + half of distance `1 + 0.5`

Etc. You see what you are doing is basically interpolating the block position towards the `transform.position`, not how it should be to the center between the original position and `transform.position`!

---

So one solution (I don't see your full code) would be to store the original `z` position and make sure you are always at the center between that original position and the current `transform.position`

```
block.position = originalBlockPosition + Vevtor3.forward * (transform.position - originalBlockPosition).z / 2f;
```

---

As mentioned way simpliest though would be to rather just create a parent for your object and make an offset this that the parent is exactly the pivot you want to scale around. Somewhat like

```
*-ParentPivot
[*****Your Block*****]
```

This way you can simply scale the parent and the block will always be stretched correctly! You would only have to make sure your block by default has a width of 1 unit the you could directly use something like

```
parent.localScale = new Vevtor3(1, 1, transform.position.z - parent.position.z);
```